# Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>] when upgrade spring-boot-actuator 1.2.5.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator

I am using spring-boot-actuator dependency with version 1.1.2 with non spring boot application, now I want to upgrade to version 1.2.5.RELEASE to use the default chipped health endpoint in my application.

When I upgrade to 1.2.5.RELEASE the application fails to start up with error

```
 Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]
```

I can see the configurationlocation is being set as NONE in AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext so in the XmlBeanDefinitionReader it fails with this error.

Any help is appreciated.

here is the full stack trace:

```
[INFO ] 2017-11-30 16:25:47.714 [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1]        c.w.w.u.s.MyPropertiesInitializer - Registering PropertySource my-eventhub.config with Spring Environment
[ERROR] 2017-11-30 16:31:13.914 [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1]                     o.s.w.c.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:515) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1809) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.64]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.64]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 59 more
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was when upgrading to spring-boot-actuator 1.2.5.RELEASE, for some reason the "contextConfigLocation" was removed so all I neded to do is to specify the contextConfiguration in my web.xml which is by default /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: what about application without applicationContext, annotations only?

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov there is no application without applicationContext

Comment: @Roberto: I have an annotations only app that is failing on startup with a similar error [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62761318/beandefinitionstoreexception-ioexception-parsing-xml-document-from-servletconte). How do you configure an annotations only app?