# BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, apache-camel

I have an Apache Camel v3.3 project that works fine as a stand-alone application but I'm struggling to deploy it to Tomcat.

The error I get is:

```
Jul 06, 2020 5:53:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:637)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5653)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1327)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:685)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:209)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:333)
    ... 46 more
```

The pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!--Get required dependencies from parent -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>commissionly.io</groupId>
    <artifactId>c10y-integration-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <camel.version>3.3.0</camel.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.2.7.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <run.profiles>dev</run.profiles>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <!--Import as a pom to let spring-boot to manage spring-boot dependency 
                versions -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!--Import as a pom to let camel to manage camel-spring-boot dependency 
                versions -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${camel.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
    
        <!-- Camel Starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Component: Serve HTTP requests by a Servlet. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Data format: Marshal POJOs to JSON and back -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Component: Not in List of Starters https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/list.html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Component: Send requests to external HTTP servers using Apache HTTP Client 4.x. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Component: Log messages to the underlying logging mechanism. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-log-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Component: Perform SQL queries using Spring JDBC. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-sql-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Component: Access databases through SQL and JDBC. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jdbc-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <!--Spring boot dependencies to enable WEB, JDBC and TOMCAT features -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2019/04/deploy-spring-boot-application-tomcat.html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- Component: Expose HTTP endpoints using the HTTP server available in the current platform. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-platform-http-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Use CXF HTTP transport to run Camel in Tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For Hortio console to detect Camel Context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-management</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL JDBC connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.20</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SQL Server JDBC driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.2.jre11</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Required for Base64 encoding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version -->
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version>}</source>
                    <target>${java.version>}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

<!-- 
    Angelo Immediata comment: only Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet' is required.
    See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47651035/spring-context-initialization-failed-even-after-well-defining-the-classpath
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
 -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
 
 </web-app>
```

I've tried with and without `ContextLoaderListener`; the same error is raised.

My code is entirely @Annotated so I have no apache-config or spring-config files.

How can I prevent the startup in Tomcat from trying to read a file that doesn't exist - I guess that's what `[/<NONE>]` means? - because the file's not necessary.

My goal is to run my Camel app in Tomcat so I can use Hawtio Console for observation & management.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be due to the missing  tag which defines the location of the camel XMl files. Please check the official guide [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/servlet-tomcat-example.html)

Also, if you want to monitor camel using hawtio, you can do it even without deploying it to Tomcat with the help of jolokia. You need pass JVM arg -javaagent: and run hawtio in standalone mode.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy.

The following two Spring dependencies were required:

```
<!--Spring boot dependencies to enable WEB and TOMCAT features -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And a web starter app was also needed:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

/**
 * See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    
}
```

No configuration was necessary - e.g. no `web.xml`.

And that's it! It all worked first time and flawlessly after that.